# If $\|f\|_p = \infty$ and $\|g\|_p = \infty$, $p >1$, do we have $\|f+g\|_p = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\|{f}\|_p = \infty$ and $\|g\|_p = \infty$, $p >1$, do we have $\|f+g\|_p = \infty?$ Both $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be non-negative.

I believe this should be true, but how to prove it? My thought is that I should use the inequality $(a+b)^p \geq a^p+b^p$ if both $a, b$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

Use $$f(x)+\underbrace{g(x)}_{\geq 0}\geq f(x)$$
for all $x$ to get that, since $p>0$,
$$(f(x)+g(x))^p\geq f(x)^p$$
for all $x$, and then conclude that $$\lVert f+g\rVert_p^p \geq \lVert f\rVert_p^p$$

Comment: (Note that the conclusion holds even if only one of the two nonnegative functions has infinite norm.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ and $g$ are non-negative and $t\mapsto t^p$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, it follows that
$$ (f+g)^p\geq g^p $$
Therefore
$$||f+g||_p^p=\int (f+g)^p\geq \int g^p=||g||_p^p=\infty$$
and so $||f+g||_p=\infty$.